Opencv with nodejs
I'm encountering an issue with opencv4nodejs in my Node.js application. After configuring opencv4nodejs to use a custom OpenCV installation built from source in /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/, I'm receiving the following error when I try to start my application:
Error: Cannot find module '/root/Dashboard-Accounts/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build/Release/opencv4nodejs'
Require stack:

/root/Dashboard-Accounts/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js
/root/Dashboard-Accounts/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/opencv4nodejs.js
/root/Dashboard-Accounts/dist/users/users.service.js
/root/Dashboard-Accounts/dist/users/users.module.js
/root/Dashboard-Accounts/dist/app.module.js
/root/Dashboard-Accounts/dist/main.js

my node version is 22
I have changed by package.json like this
"opencv4nodejs": {
    "disableAutoBuild": 1,
    "opencvIncludeDir": "/usr/local/include/opencv4",
    "opencvLibDir": "/usr/local/lib",
    "opencvBinDir": "/usr/local/bin",
    "opencvDir": "/usr/local/lib"
}

I want to get resolved this issue. I have try everything.
